# Isomorphic free groups - SymPy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, algebra

I wonder if there is a function on the SymPy module (Python) which determines whether two free groups are isomorphic.

For example, given the following free groups :

```
F, a, b = free_group("a, b")
F1 = FpGroup(F, [a**2, b**3, (a*b)**4])

G, a, b = free_group("a, b")
G1 = FpGroup(G, [a**3, b**5])
```

is there a native function in the module SymPy ?

If not, how can I create such a function, still using SymPy tools ?

Thank you very much,
Respectfully,

AF

Comment: Note that F1 and G1 are not free groups.  They are finitely presented groups.  Determining if two free groups are isomorphic is a lot easier.